# chained selection drop down small misfunction

Tags: php, html

i'm working on this 4 chained drop down selection and everything is working alright, this is how it works.

Semester: you select a semester

subject: after selecting a semester, you choose a subject

section: after selecting a subject, you choose which section

professor: after selecting a section, you choose which professor depending on the section chosen.

The problem is that when it comes to professor, it would fetch all professors from the database instead the one professor assigned to that class and section. For example i do this:

semester: fall-2015

subject: csis 330

section: 1

professor: should show jason but it shows all professors that teach a section of number 1 (problem is it needs to check for professor that teaches the subject chosen and section chosen, not only section as it bring all professors teaching a section number 1)

i hope you got the idea.

Here is my code below:

func.php

```
<html>
<?php
//**************************************
//     Page load dropdown results     //
//**************************************
function getTierOne()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT semester FROM three_drops") 
    or die(mysql_error());

      while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

        {
           echo '<option value="'.$tier['semester'].'">'.$tier['semester'].'</option>';
        }

}

//**************************************
//     First selection results     //
//**************************************
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_1" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
   drop_1($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM three_drops WHERE semester='$drop_var'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
        <br /><br />  <label for="subject" accesskey="s">Subject</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php
    echo '<select name="drop_2" id="drop_2">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['subject'].'">'.$drop_2['subject'].'</option>';
            }



    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_2').hide();
    $('#drop_2').change(function(){
      $('#wait_2').show();
      $('#result_2').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_2\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_2').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_2').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_section('result_2', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}


//**************************************
//     Second selection results     //
//**************************************
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_2" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
   drop_2($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_2($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT section FROM three_drops WHERE subject='$drop_var'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
        ?>
        <br /><br />  <label for="section" accesskey="s">Section</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php
    echo '<select name="drop_3" id="drop_3">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

           while($drop_3 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_3['section'].'">'.$drop_3['section'].'</option>';
            }

                echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_3').hide();
    $('#drop_3').change(function(){
      $('#wait_3').show();
      $('#result_3').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_3\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_3').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_3').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_professor('result_3', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}


//**************************************
//     Third selection results     //
//**************************************
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_3" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
   drop_3($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_3($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT professor FROM three_drops WHERE section='$drop_var'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
        ?>
        <br /><br />  <label for="professor" accesskey="s">Professor</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php
    echo '<select name="drop_4" id="drop_4">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

           while($drop_4 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_4['professor'].'">'.$drop_4['professor'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select> ';
}
?>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
  include('db.php');
  include('func.php');
  ?>
 <div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait_1').hide();
    $('#drop_1').change(function(){
      $('#wait_1').show();
      $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "drop_1",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#wait_1').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
function finishAjax_section(id, response) {
  $('#wait_2').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
function finishAjax_professor(id, response) {
  $('#wait_3').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>
      <label for="semester" accesskey="s">Semester</label>&nbsp;
    <select name="drop_1" id="drop_1">

      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Category</option>

      <?php getTierOne(); ?>

    </select> 

    <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span id="wait_2" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_2" style="display: none;"></span>
     <span id="wait_3" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
        <span id="result_3" style="display: none;"></span>

</div>
```

Database is like this:

```
semester  | subject  | section | professor 
Fall-2015 | ELEG-330 |    1    | Jason     
Fall-2015 | ELEG-330 |    2    | Michael
Fall-2015 | ELEG-210 |    1    | kyle
```

For example above if the semester was fall 2015, subject was eleg-330 and section 1, the professor would show both jason and kyle which is incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have `... WHERE section='$drop_var' AND subject='$resulta'"`, but you don't define `$resulta` in `function drop_3($drop_var)`.

Comment: i don't know what to define, i did that to actually start something but i don't know, imagine its not there,

Comment: @Sean removed it since it was rubbish i just put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you need to change your `$.get()` in `function drop_2($drop_var)` so that it passes the other data

```
function drop_2($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    ...[your other code]...

                echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_3').hide();
    $('#drop_3').change(function(){
      $('#wait_3').show();
      $('#result_3').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_3\",
        drop_var1: $('#drop_1').val(), //semester
        drop_var2: $('#drop_2').val(), //subject
        drop_var3: $('#drop_3').val()  //section
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_3').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_professor('result_3', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}
```

then in your `function drop_3()`, you need to add the other parameters

```
//**************************************
//     Third selection results     //
//**************************************
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_3" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
   drop_3($_GET['drop_var1'],$_GET['drop_var2'],$_GET['drop_var3']); 
}

function drop_3($drop_var1,$drop_var2,$drop_var3)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT professor FROM three_drops WHERE  semester='$drop_var1' AND subject='$drop_var2' AND section='$drop_var3'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
        ?>
        ...[rest of your code]...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing the the previous information along each subsequent step. Pass the subject to the third function, by adding it to your get, like so:

```
$('#drop_3').change(function(){
    $('#wait_3').show();
    $('#result_3').hide();
    $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_3\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_3').val(),
        prev_var: '".$drop_var."' // added $prev_var here
    }, function(response){
        $('#result_3').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_professor('result_3', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Then pass it to a second param in your third function, and use it in the query:

```
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_3" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
   drop_3($_GET['drop_var'], $_GET['prev_var'); 
}
function drop_3($drop_var, $prev_var) // $prev_var here
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT professor FROM three_drops WHERE section='$drop_var' AND subject='$prev_var'") // $prev_var here
    or die(mysql_error());

    //etc.
}
```